# What exactly does each of Local / Express IIS / External Host bring?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, iis

I'm currently in the learnings of `ASP.NET MVC` and I've read about what `IIS` is and what it is needed for, but I'm somewhat confused about what the difference between `Local IIS` and `Express IIS` is, and also, what `External Host` is and how it could be used. What context would each of these be suitable in?

Comment: do you have access to `Google` from your immediate location, this is something you honestly could have easily found by doing a simple google search in my opinion

Comment: I do have access to `Google` from my immediate location, could you help and tell me the search query that returns the answer(s) to my question?

Answer (score 2):

- **Local IIS**. The IIS that comes with Microsoft Windows as an add-in enabling the feature from the control panel. It's both available in some editions of home-oriented products and Windows Server System.
- **IIS Express**. A simplified IIS with few options and no GUI to use it as simple development server. Since some Visual Studio versions is already installed as part of its installation/setup.
- **External host**. I suspect that it refers to configuring a host to be reachable outside of your own machine.

Comment: External Host allows you to connect to a non-express (full) instance of IIS. I use the IIS running on my local machine, but it probably works for an external server too if you configure it correctly.